# Flow.js does not know that ComponentProps exists in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

```
// @flow
import React, { type Element, ComponentProps } from 'react';

interface ButtonProps extends ComponentProps<'button'> {
  name: string;
}
const Button = (props: ButtonProps): Element<'button'> => {
  const { children } = props;
  return <button {...props}>{children}</button>;
};

export default function ButtonTest() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button name="sahil" style={{ margin: 20 }}>
        Sahil Kapoor
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above code, a red line comes below ComponentProps. This is because Flow.js doesn't recognize that ComponentProps exists in React.

The exact Flow.js error is - 
Cannot import `ComponentProps` because there is no `ComponentProps` export in `react`.

How should I resolve this issue of Flow.js not knowing that ComponentProps exists in React?

Comment: Hey @invalidtoken, for the sake of searching and clarity, let alone us helping you- could you post the code as a snippet instead of a screenshot here?

Comment: @Roberrrt nice one :))

Comment: Does it work if you reference it as React.ComponentProps?

Comment: Also, what version of React are you using?

Comment: @JayKariesch The same error comes when using React.ComponentProps. My React version is 16.8.6 and my Flow.js version is 0.96.0

Comment: Why do you think that flow type ComponentProps exists in React?